Problem 1.131 Robert Megginson
Let $E$ be a normed vector space of infinite dimension. If $U \subset E^*$ is a nonempty set which is open with respect to the weak-* topology, how can we show that it is not strongly bounded?
I have tried by contradiction to arrive at Riesz's lemma so as to arrive at space of finite dimension, but it doesn't seem to work for the case of infinite dimension.
Problem

What do you mean by Riesz's lemma?

@LidingYao that if the closed unit ball is compact, then the space is of finite dimension

Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764997
